# What are the standard practices in humanities around making my writing open access?

Tags: humanities, history

I'm new to art history/humanities and recently wrote a short essay for a museum magazine. I come from the sciences and would typically make a free version of my papers available on a preprint server like arXiv. The essay I wrote is not peer-reviewed, but people would need to buy the magazine to read it. I'm going to ask the publisher if I can put an open-access version on my website, but is there a standard of practice in humanities to make essays publicly available if they are behind paywalls like scientists do for journals? Are there specific hosting sites for humanities preprints?

Comment: Since it's not peer-reviewed and in a magazine rather than a journal, is this a piece of research or more popularly-oriented writing?  Scientific American or National Geographic articles aren't usually available as preprints either!

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I guess it's more popularly-oriented. I'm not entirely sure where the line is now. Pros/cons: I did a bunch of research to write it (+1), I don't expect it to be cited (-1), but people do sometimes cite artist essays (+1), it's quite short (-1) but I still want to share it with people who follow my work (+1). I wasn't paid to write it if that makes a difference.

Comment: So, I'm also moving on from the life sciences to the humanities, and I would say that in the humanities, it will often depend on the conditions of the periodical where you will publish it. Preprints are not so hot in the humanities because discoveries are often not so fundamental that they have to get out immediately.